# What is happening to my file with res.download in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I'm working on an app that creates a PDF document on the server, then displays a `Download Here` button. When I click the button, the process appears to work. When I inspect the Network>Preview and Network>Headers tabs in the Chrome console I can see that the file has definitely been returned.

The problem is, it does not display and it does not offer the option to save. Am I missing a client side step here? My preferred outcome is either to give the user the option to save the file or to automatically begin the download to their default path.

Here is relevant the server code:

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
 var file = req.params.id;
 var filePath = __dirname + '../../../lib/completedforms/';
 var thisPath = path.resolve(filePath + file);
 res.attachment(thisPath);
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
 res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
 res.download(thisPath);
};
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance here.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for both `res.attachment()` *AND* `res.download()`. Just use the latter.

Also, `res.download()` already sets the `Content-Disposition` header, so you can remove that too.

You can also simplify your path generation:

```
var thisPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../lib/completedforms/', file);
```

Although you should probably sanitize `file` and/or check that `thisPath` is not some location where it shouldn't be. This will prevent someone from supplying a potentially malicious `req.params.id` value like `../../../../../../../etc/passwd`.

Comment: Thanks mscdex, that code is now a lot cleaner. I am still not getting a prompt to download though. I thought that was the whole point of the `res.download()` method. I can write the return value to the page, and it definitely is the encoded PDF file. I thought that the browser would recognize the format but evidently that's not the case.

Comment: @mscdex @espressoAndCode I too am trying to get the browser to prompt for download. In my case, `res.download()` is successfully downloading the file, but it's downloading to whatever directory is my default AND it's opening the file immediately. Any way to avoid opening the file?